# Different numerical operations for different factors in a variable in R

Tags: r

Let's assume I have this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = 1:6,
                 V2 = rep(c("DC1", "DC2"), each = 3),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

How can I operate differently according to DC1 and DC2?

Let's say I would like to multiply by 3 V1 values that belong to DC1, and divide by 2 those values that belong to DC2.

Comment: What have you tried? Take a look at `?ifelse`. `df$V3 <- ifelse(df$V2 == "DC1", df$V1 * 3, df$V1 / 2)`

Comment: `f <- data.frame(V2=c("DC1", "DC2"), mult=c(3, 0.5));
df2 <- merge(df, f); df2$result <- with(df2, V1*mult)`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. They worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grepl` and `ifelse`
For DC1 you can use

```
df$V1 <- ifelse(grepl("DC1", df$V2), df$V1 * 3, df$V1)
```

And for DC2 you can use

```
df$V1 <- ifelse(grepl("DC2", df$V2), df$V1 / 2, df$V1)
```

Using both these lines results in

```
   V1  V2
1 3.0 DC1
2 6.0 DC1
3 9.0 DC1
4 2.0 DC2
5 2.5 DC2
6 3.0 DC2
```

If you want more and different operations you could make use of `functions` and a `for` loop.